# Cómo obtener los valores de los segundos productos más caros de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT MAX(f.monto) FROM (SELECT * FROM Producto WHERE Id_local = 1) as f WHERE f.monto NOT IN (SELECT MAX(f2.monto) FROM (SELECT * FROM Producto WHERE Id_local = 1) AS f2);
```

Pero esta consulta sólo me trae el valor para los locales con id 1. Sin embargo, necesito que me traiga, al mismo tiempo, el valor para los locales con id 2

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Si existiera un Producto F en el local 1 con monto 70000, te debería retornar A y F? O solo alguno de los 2?

Comment: sí señor, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería esta:

```
select * 
from Producto p1 
join (
select max(monto) as monto, id_local from Producto group by id_local
)t
on p1.monto < t.monto and p1.id_local = t.id_local
```

Se crea una sub consulta que trae el monto máximo por local. Luego se hace un join y se traen los registros de la tabla p1 donde el monto sea menor que el monto máximo para el local actual.

Comment: Muchas gracias, bro!

Comment: Y si cambiamos el monto del producto E a 40 mil, que retornaría? @WilliamPinedaMHA